# && statement javascript not evaluated

Tags: javascript

I try to write javascript code for OS detection. 
I use navigator.appVersion to generate a variable and then evaluate it. The I use indexOf on that variable for evaluation on a if else statement.
Using string variables like "Windows", "Linux", "iPhone", ..... i evaluate the OS.
On Android phones I observed that navigator.appVersion return something like this:

"5.0 (Linux; U; Android .....)"

so I generated this code to resolve the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var Windows="Windows";
        var Safari="Safari";
var OSName=navigator.appVersion;
alert(OSName);
function OS() {
if (OSName.indexOf(Linux)!=-1 && OSName.indexOf(Android)!=-1) {
        alert("Goooood");
} else {
    alert("Baddddd");
    }
}
</script>
```

The thing is that the && does not evaluate (returns Baddddd...).

Any clue would help.

Comment: You should put quotes around `Linux` and `Android`

Comment: I do not get it. See the result here: http://www.geographgis.com/jq/os.html

Answer (score 5):

From the code you have provided you have not defined the variables `Linux` and `Android`.

Try

```
var Linux="Linux";
var Android="Android";
```

After your declaration of Windows and Safari.

Comment: That would cause a Reference Error, and not allow any alert to happen. I'm guessing it's a typo in the question.

Comment: It is possible the OP is unaware of any errors that may have been caused as this is javascript.

Comment: Except that OP stated that the code *"(returns Badddddd...)"*, which wouldn't be possible if there's a Reference Error.

Comment: Ah yes, fair point. Either way though s/he needs to fix this issue.

Comment: You probably meant `var Android="Android";` in your answer. ;)

Comment: Oops! Yes indeed that is what I meant. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Is that the actual code? It looks like you are not quoting your Strings in the indexOf check?

```
I believe it should be:
if (OSName.indexOf('Linux')!=-1 && OSName.indexOf('Android')!=-1) {
```

Or are Linux and Android String variables not shown in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Windows="Windows";
    var Safari="Safari";
var OSName=navigator.appVersion;
alert(OSName);
function OS() {
if ((OSName.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) && (OSName.indexOf("Android")!=-1)) {
    alert("Goooood");
} else {
alert("Baddddd");
}
}
</script>
```